# How to remove Macintosh HD from desktop?

Tags: hard-drive, catalina

I don't even know how, but this Macintosh HD logo is stuck on my desktop, and it wasn't like that a couple of days ago.
Don't see anyway to remove it or eject it from Desktop.

Thanks (;

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to Finder's preferences and on its General tab under "Show these items on the desktop:", uncheck: Hard disks

[image: Finder's preferences]

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all icons from you desktop by typing

```
defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop false
killall Finder
```

in the terminal. This gives you a clean desktop.

Typing

```
defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop true
killall Finder
```

retuns the items to you desktop.

Comment: why the downvote.  this works??